# Differential equation of parabolas having axis parallel to x-axis

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

I get the whole discussion but why are we only considering $(y-\beta)^2 = a(x - \alpha)$ and not $(y-\beta)^2 = -a(x - \alpha)$.

After All  $(y-\beta)^2 = -a(x - \alpha)$ also has its axis parallel to the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except perhaps for the words "latus rectum", don't the equations also work just as well when $a$ is negative? For example, $\alpha = \beta=0$ and $a=-1$ gives us $y^2=-x$. Is there a parabola with axis parallel to the $x$-axis that cannot be described by $(y-\beta)^2 = a(x - \alpha)$?